# Convert byteArray to String

Tags: c++, cardreader

I am a beginner in C++ and try to get a output from a card reader:
For this i use a DLL. My problem is that my response returns a byteArray and I would like to convert it to a normal string. So my actual code currently is:

```
res = CT_data(ctn, &dad, &sad, 5, command, &lenr, response);
printf("\nThe Response: %s", response);
```

This prints to my console:

```
The Response: ò
```

But in the documentation it says that if the connection with the device works it should return `9500` or `9000`!

So I think I have to transform the `response`! How can I do this? Thanks.

**From the documentation:**

```
nSuccess = CT_data(CT_data(ctn,dad,sad,lenc,commando,lenr,response)
```

ctn: Integer, 16 Bit, Unsigned  (interne Terminalnummer aus CT_INIT)
     dad: Integer, 8 Bit, Unsigned (Destination-Adress)
sad: Integer, 8 Bit, Unsigned (Source-Adress)
lenc: Integer 16 Bit, Unsigned ( Länge des Commandos  )
 commando: Byte-Array , (Kommando)
 lenr: Integer 16 Bit, Unsigned (Länge der Response)
response: Byte-Array ( Antwort)
nSuccess: Integer, 8 Bit, Signed ( 0 = Erfolgreich, -1 = Fehlerhaft)

```
nSuccess = CT_data(ctn,dad,sad,lenc,command[],lenr,response[])
```

Wenn nSuccess = 0, dann response[] prüfen. Wenn response =  9000 oder 9500 war das     CT_Reset erfolgreich.  Als nächstes dann die Kartenanforderung

```
typedef CHAR (WINAPI *CT_DATA) (USHORT, UCHAR*, UCHAR*, USHORT, UCHAR*, USHORT*, UCHAR*);
```

Comment: Did you verify that `CT_data()` actually works = did you check the `res` return value? A value different from zero indicates that there was an issue and in that case the value inside `response`can be discarded as invalid.

Comment: @PhilipAllgaier i tried to check it with `printf("\nResponse Code: " + res);` after the command but somehow it only prints to my console: `Response Code:` So i'm not 100% sure if it worked? Can you please show me how i can test it? Thanks!

Comment: @JohnSmith `printf("\nResponse Code: %d", res);`

Comment: Yes `res` returns `0` so this seems to work! The problem is really the format of the `response`

Comment: You may want to provide the definitions of the other arguments involved in your function call, and some details of the called function as well (e.g. are there string buffers involved? Should they be allocated at the call site, or are they allocated by the function and returned back? Is there a buffer length specified? etc.)

Comment: @PhilipAllgaier i added parts from the documentation to my question ! I hope you can help me with this further! Thanks

Comment: I tried `printf("\nResponse: %d", response);` and this returned `Response: 16379912` So wich format do i need?

Comment: How did you define `response` in your code? From what you added in your post, it seems that it should be a buffer allocated by the caller, that is filled by the function. Moreover, did you pass proper length value for this buffer to the `CT_data()` function?

Comment: My problem is that i am beginner in c++! So i thought it would be better if i post the whole code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/11cZNj2nBASEo81DH7HKNHb-89J2PvMfVP8taAsX-YrE/edit?usp=sharing I hope this helps! Thanks again for your help! You are really a great person!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could the reponse mentioned in the documentation be 2 bytes in hex? Then the response length, i.e. the return value of the CT_data() call, should be 2; and the first byte of the reponse array should be 0x90 or 0x95, i.e. 144 or 149, while the second byte should always be 0. Not sure what byte renders ò in your code page.

Comment: maybe with the docu i added to my question you can help me further! Thanks!

Comment: I think your right in the docu it says: `die letzten beiden Bytes von Response auswerten: 9000 = Erfolgreich` As you are german! I appreciate this! Maybe you can say me how i can select the two last 2 bytes? Thanks

Comment: Ah, thanks for the doc. So the response length is in the int pointed to by lenr. Then the last two bytes in response hold the status bytes -- remember, indices are 0 based, i.e. lenr-1 is last: success = (response[lenr-2]==0x95||response[lenr-2]==0x90) && response[lenr-1] == 0;

Comment: @PeterSchneider: the codepage is obviously cp850 (or cp858), where ò is at 0x95

Comment: Here is my full code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/11cZNj2nBASEo81DH7HKNHb-89J2PvMfVP8taAsX-YrE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @PeterSchneider thanks again for your help! I will try it tomorrow and  report you my progress! Thanks